# Choosing a subset containing exactly one of any two elements

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A$ be a set with $|A|=n\geq 1$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of sets containing more than half of all subsets of $A$. Prove that we can choose $\lceil\log_2n\rceil+1$ sets from $\mathcal{F}$ so that for any $a,b\in A$ with $a\neq b$, some chosen set contains exactly one of $a,b$.

First, it is fine to assume that $\mathcal{F}$ contains one more than half of all subsets of $A$ (i.e., $2^{n-1}+1$ of them), since this makes the problem only harder. For $n=2$, $\mathcal{F}$ must contain at least one of $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$, so the statement holds. For $n=3$, if $\mathcal{F}$ contains at least two of the singleton sets, we are done. Otherwise $\mathcal{F}$ must contain at least two sets with two elements, and we are also done. However, for $n=4$ the casework is starting to add up.

Comment: $\lceil \log_2n\rceil$ is a recurrent quantity when dealing with binary search problems. Perhaps there's a binary search hidden somewhere.

Comment: hi, is this conjecture known to be true?  is there a source?  what kinds of problems does induction run into?  I like the question!